# Solution for many spring boot processes to read and update data in one table

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

It seems that **shedlock** works in this case, but what I want here is that all processes on multiple nodes run at the same time, unlike shedlock, which locks the table and can only be accessed by the locked person.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Thanks so much for the help

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided out-of-the-box by Spring Boot Data JPA is based on locking of the specified row of the database table. It can be locked either

- just for reading - to avoid so called dirty reads
- or for update - to avoid overwriting of changes made by somebody else.

Depending on your business case you can choose optimistic or pessimistic locking. The former is simpler and should be preferred when your application mostly reads data and only rarely update it. The latter can be used in the opposite case or if the more advance logic is needed.

For more details and code examples you can check:

1. https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-optimistic-locking
2. https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-pessimistic-locking